# Manipular arquivo usando shell script

Tags: variáveis, script, bash, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou precisando criar um shell script para verificar se existe um arquivo no diretório, se sim, armazenar o nome desse arquivo em uma variável e depois manipular para realizar algumas cópias.

Segue o código inicial que estou fazendo.

```
#!/bin/bash
ARQUIVO=SD


if [ $SD -e /tmp/ ]; then

echo 'ARQUIVO EXITE NA PASTA'

'echo -e '\n\n


echo 'ACESSANDO O DIRETORIO /tmp'

cd /

cd /tmp

cp -r /tmp/$SD /teste

echo 'COPIANDO ARQUIVO'

cd /

cd /teste

cp $SD teste.DAT


echo 'ARQUIVO COPIADO COM SUCESSO'                                                                 

read -p ''

echo '#########EXCLUINDO ARQUIVO(S).IPM DA PASTA /tmp#########' 

rm -r  /tmp/$SD

rm -r /teste

echo '#################ARQUIVO EXCLUÍDO#######################'

else

echo '#ARQUIVO NÃO EXISTE E NÃO COPIADO  #'
echo -e '\n\n'

fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Seu script esta quase, mas contem alguns pequenos erros. Compare com esse que está funcionando:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARQUIVO=teste.tmp

if [ -f /tmp/$ARQUIVO ]; then
        echo -e 'ARQUIVO EXISTE NA PASTA \n\n'
        echo 'COPIANDO ARQUIVO'
        cp  /tmp/$ARQUIVO /flex/dv2/seq/trm/teste.DAT
        echo 'ARQUIVO COPIADO COM SUCESSO'
        read -p 'Pressione qq tecla para excluir arquivo original'
        echo '#########EXCLUINDO ARQUIVO(S).IPM DA PASTA /tmp#########'
        rm   /tmp/$ARQUIVO
        echo '#################ARQUIVO EXCLUIDO#######################'
else
        echo '#ARQUIVO N EXISTE E N COPIADO  # \n\n'
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Está bem completo, mas contem alguns erro de sintaxe como o if.
Metodo correto: if [ -e $XXX  ]; then
Segue um exemplo abaixo.

````
```
if [ -e "$hoje" ];
    then
        cd /fs1/save/bk/
            mv -f srt03.f307.cafet_* $bkps/$hoje
    else
        mkdir $hoje
            chmod 777 $hoje
                cd /fs1/save/bk/
                    mv -f srt03.f307.cafet_* $bkps/$hoje
fi;
    ```
````